# In SAYC, what does doubling a 2-level weak jump overcall mean?

Tags: bridge

In SAYC, what does doubling a 2-level weak jump overcall mean?  For example, the bidding sequence: 1♣ - 2♠ - double.

Is it

1. a negative double,
2. a penalty double,
3. a show of spade control, or
4. something else?

What distribution and values does it promise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This filled out convention card for SAYC](http://www.acbl.org/documentlibrary/play/sayc_card.pdf) indicates that negative doubles are played through 2S. By this agreement (which could be amended by partnership agreement, but which invalidate the claim to be playing *pure* SAYC) the double of a 2S jump overcall is a Negative Double. This bid should indicate 4+ hearts and game invitational values (10+ points), and generally deny any particular strength in spades.

If the jump overcall were above the level of 2S, such as in the auction

> 1H - 3D - double,

it wold be a penalty double showing diamonds and suggesting the collection of a penalty against a 3D contract.